# Soundcloud player background css trick

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css, soundcloud

How can I change the background to black of the soundcloud widget from http://psytology.com/artist/danny-xander/ ?

I have searched on Google, read the documentation, but this kind of widget doesn't work with the default parameter `theme_color`.

So I think, maybe I could rewrite the class that gives the background color to the player?
So I added the following lines to style.css:

```
.g-background-default {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36) !important;
}
```

(this being the class that gives color to the widget's background)

So, it didn't work, nothing happened, what can I do?

I have tried the second answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe), but it is not working. It doesn't display anything.

Comment: Is the widget link in your question a sample of what you want, or is it the widget you want to modify?

Comment: That is the widget I want to edit, the soundcloud player. I want change his CSS, so I can edit the background and the text color. (I want to make him dark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you linked to in your edit DID say that it only works when its not cross-domain meaning if the iframe src is from another domain, you can't do it...

**But** the third post in that thread did mention an interesting concept. If you use the PHP function `file_get_contents();` and get the iframe source, add the link to your style you need before the `</head>` and replace the iframe with your own PHP file, you may get it to work. He said he did it with Google Calendar.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521755/2748713 -- Link to the relevent post from the thread you found

Comment: I said I have tried the second answer, and did not work. that is the second answer that is not working. I am working with flash, probably thats why. Google Calendar provides only html and css into that iframe, so thats why its working in that case.

Comment: Still, being able to "inject" css styles into the iframe using javascript should work because the embedded SoundCloud isn't flash.

Comment: I know this is years old, but please accept if this helped you.